# Kendo angular 2 grid dblclick - IE Pointer event vs Chrome Mouse Event

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am developing a data grid using [Kendo Angular 2 Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/).

I have written a grid event listener as

`(dblclick)="dblClickEvent($event)"`.

and handler as

`dblClickEvent(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }`

Now after running in Chrome the emitting event is **MouseEvent** but in IE 11 it is **PointerEvent**

1. How to handle this.
2. Also I want to check the source of this events, is it a row or other than row (like columnHeader row)

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to this question earlier but i forgot to post here.

```js
DblClick(event: MouseEvent)
{
    if (event.srcElement instanceof HTMLTableCellElement) 
    {
      if (event.srcElement.outerHTML.toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf("KENDOGRIDCELL") != -1) 
      {
      //Your code here
      }
    }
}
```

Above it the workaround for  my scenario